# Select Distinct with Sum

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2016

There is an employee table with an entry reordered per person per day.

I created this query and it works, but instead of the total hours worked this past week, it should be the sum of the total hours the employee has since the beginning of time.

Would someone be able to help? I am lost.  Thank you.

```
SELECT SSN, firstname, Lastname, SUM(CAST(Hours as float)) AS HourstoDate 
FROM Employees
WHERE CAST(Scheduled as datetime) >= DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, GetDate()-5 ), 0 )
GROUP BY SSN, Lastname, FirstName

SSN     FirstName   LastName    Scheduled       Hours
1234    Jane        Doe         Monday 9/26     10
1234    Jane        Doe         Tuesday 9/27    10
```

It should pull Jane's entry since she worked this week, but hours needs to be 1525, not the 20 she worked this week.

Comment: Is it as simple as taking out the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: put table structure and some insert data. It will help in debugging your query.

Comment: The where needs to be there because it can only be people that worked the last week, not since the beginning of time.

Answer (score 0):

The query is not working because you are conflating two searches in one, on the same table. You cannot search for records after a certain date AND at the same time retrieve all records from the beginning of time.

In these cases my approach is to join the table with itself. Ideally it should be something like:

```
select
  z.ssn
, z.firstname
, z.lastname
, sum ( cast ( eo.hours as float ) ) as hourstodate
from (
    select distinct
      ei.ssn
    , ei.firstname
    , ei.lastname
    from
      employees ei
    where
          cast ( ei.scheduled as datetime ) > dateadd ( ei.d , datediff ( ei.d , 0 , getdate() - 5 ) , 0 )
) z
join employees eo on ( z.ssn = eo.ssn and z.firstname = eo.firstname and z.lastname = eo.lastname )
group by
  z.ssn
, z.lastname
, z.firstdate
```

I can't try it so I can't guarantee it will work. Feel free to add a comment if it returns an error.

EDIT: mistype

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your filter so that it sums ALL hours *first*, then makes sure the "worked this week" condition is satisfied (using a `having` clause), like this:

```
SELECT SSN, firstname, Lastname, SUM(CAST(Hours as float)) AS HourstoDate, max(case when CAST(Scheduled as datetime) >= DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, GetDate()-5 ), 0 ) then 1 else 0 end) as worked_this_week
FROM Employees
GROUP BY SSN, Lastname, FirstName
HAVING max(case when CAST(Scheduled as datetime) >= DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, GetDate()-5 ), 0 ) then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```